# Passing constant values to functions through Constraints in Z3

Tags: python, z3py

I observed in Z3 that if I use a function in my constraints for the Solver, then I cannot pass it a constant value.

For example:

In the function below, gen() is a function which takes 2 inputs. The first input is a BitVec() which represents a string of length 10. The second parameter to the gen() function will be used for some calculation in it. However, I noticed that even though I am passing a constant value as the second parameter through the constraints, the value is different inside the function when Z3 is solving the equation.

```
from z3 import *

def gen(input, v):
    outer_counter = v

    for i in range(len(input)):


    return result

s = Solver()

input = [BitVec("input%s" % i, 8) for i in range(10)]

s.add(gen(input, 0) == 0xAABBCCDD)
s.add(gen(input, 1) == 0xABCDABCD)
```

So, is there a way in Z3 to invoke a function through constraints and also pass it a fixed value?

Comment: Looks like your `gen` function is missing the body of its `for` loop. (`result` is never defined.) Without seeing what's in there, it's impossible to answer your question!

Comment: @Levent Erkok Yeah, I will update those details soon. Thanks